# Breaking excel table into text file - formatting

Tags: vba, formatting

I am using the below VBA to create text files from a 3-column excel spreadsheet.  How can i prevent it from using scientific notation.  It creates issues when the files are used..  Thanks

```
Sub Button4_Click()

Dim myFile As String

Dim cellValue As Double

Dim i As Long

Dim j As Integer

Dim t As Long

Dim n As Long

Dim V(1 To 3) As Variant

'n is the number of lines to be placed in each table

'numseg is the total number of files to be produced

Dim numseg As Integer

n = 400

numseg = 13

For t = 1 To numseg

myFile = Application.DefaultFilePath & "/dw_files/xxxx/test1/Segment_" & t & ".pts"

Open myFile For Output As #1

For i = 0 To (n - 1)
        
    For j = 1 To 3
        
 V(j) = CDbl(Cells(((t - 1) * (n - 1) + i + 1), j).Value)
 
    
    Next j
    
    If i < (n - 1) Then Print #1, Join(V) Else Print #1, Join(V);

Next i
                 
        Close #1

Next t

End Sub
```

Comment: Firstly, I cannot understand how your code works using slash to build a path and not back slash ("\"). Then, you cannot do anything in order to format the text in a text file you are creating, but you can open it (in Excel) properly. When you simply try opening it, Excel use `General` format and then guess what format to set according to the field/cell content. It uses scientific format for number having a big number of digits, but you can open it choosing the necessary format using `Workbooks.OpenText` with `FieldInfo` parameter like `Array(1, 2)`, 1= column number, 2 = text format.

Comment: Thanks.  So the code is called from within the open workbook.  Nothing i do using the excel format seems to change how the text files come out.